# Fat Oxidation in relation to MaxHR and V2OMax? Glucose to brain when over range?

Tags: body-fat, long-distance-running, breathing, burn-fat, blood-flow

It's my understanding that maximum body fat oxidation occurs between 47-75% of V2OMax and 70-80% of Max Heart Rate. I did a test of this theory on the treadmill, using it's metrics, and found that I was burning about 11 kcal/min or 660 kcal/hr at the maximum of this range.

What does this mean biologically? Does it mean that the maximum energy a human can metabolize from their fat stores is in this range? Does going over this range cause glucose in blood to be used or muscle protein conversion to be used as energy instead of using fat stores?

I'm trying to get an idea if my glucose/blood levels are low due to a high protein, low carbohydrate and fat diet, and I exceed these maximum ranges, if I will be starving my brain of necessary glucose it needs to function.

Comment: How did you test 11 kcal a minute? The only accurate way to do that is with a breath analyzer on a lab treadmill. The calculators on treadmills are not that accurate.

Comment: I tested it on a gym treadmill using it's metrics and my HR.  Understood, that oxygen levels require measurement for more accuracy, but this topic is really only a side point to my question.  The question is understanding what happens when exceeding these ranges inside the body.